# Get values from each string using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, match

I'm new in kotlin, i need to get each integer value and print it.

```kotlin
"""
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
"""
```

How I can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add that code to your answer and describe what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val input = """
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
"""

val regex = "\\s*int a = (\\d+);\\s*int b = (\\d+);\s*".toRegex()
val result = regex.find(input)

if (result != null) {
  val (_, a, b) = result.groupValues
  println("a is: $a")
  println("b is: $b")
} else {
  println("invalid input")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Kotlin! To achieve the same result as your provided code snippet in Kotlin, you can use the following:

```
fun main(){
   val a: Int = 5
   val b: Int = 2
   println(a)
   println(b)
}
```

This declares two variables a and b of type Int, assigns them values of 5 and 2 respectively, and then prints their values to the console using the println function. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If by the word "get" you meaning retrieving integers from this string with assignments, there your "parsing":

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val codeInString = """
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
"""
    codeInString
        .lineSequence()
        .mapNotNull(::intValueFromAssignmentLine)
        .toList()
        .let { println("assigned ints: $it") } // assigned ints: [5, 2]
}

fun intValueFromAssignmentLine(line: String) = line
    .split('=')
    .getOrNull(1) // if there will be no lines without '=', then you don't "OrNull" part here
    ?.ifEmpty { null } // and `ifEmpty` function here
    ?.dropLast(1) // drop ';'
    ?.trim()
    ?.toIntOrNull()
```